# Retrieve NSUserDefaults that haven't been used before (Swift)

Tags: swift2, nsuserdefaults

I'm loading some NSUserDefaults values when opening my app, after the first succesful sessions it works well but the issue is the first time it's opened in a new device. It tries to find values I have never filled or declared before. I tried to fix it using the following if condition, but it's still not working:

```
if NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("defaultSessionUserID")! as? String == nil{
```

but still reports me the same error:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Is it because with this line I'm only checking the object for the key and not the key? Is there any way to check if the value was created before or not?

Here's the full code:

```
if NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("defaultSessionUserID")! as? String == nil{

        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject("", forKey: "defaultSessionUserID")
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(false, forKey: "KML")
    }
    if NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("KML")! as? Bool == false{
     //Do something   
    }
    else{
     //Do something else
    }}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check both key and value type use optional binding

```
if let defaultSessionUserID = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("defaultSessionUserID") as? String {
  // key and value exists
}
```

You can register default values (e.g. in `applicationDidFinishLaunching`)

```
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
let defaultValues = ["defaultSessionUserID" : "", "KML" : false]
defaults.registerDefaults(defaultValues)
```

Then you can safely write

```
let defaultSessionUserID = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey("defaultSessionUserID")!
```

Consider that `NSUserDefaults` has dedicated methods `stringForKey` and `boolForKey`

Comment: Oh true, I could check it using `if let ...` Thanks!